# need to save a shuffled order in core data

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, core-data, shuffle

I am attempting to shuffle the order of the array in core data. Right now the code shuffles the order it attempts to save the shuffle order but when I reload the class the original order is still there.

What I am am attempting to do is in the code below. YESR is being printed int he debug section.

```
var songs = [Song]()
var index = Int()
var singer: Singer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 
    if let singer = singer {
        songs = DataManager.shared.songs(singer: singer)
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
    
    
}
 @objc func shuffleButtonPressed() {
    print("shuffle")

    // Shuffle the songs
    songs.shuffle()

    // Update the 'order' attribute for each song
    for (index, song) in songs.enumerated() {
        song.order = Int16(index)
    }

    do {
        try DataManager.shared.save() // Assuming 'DataManager.shared' is your Core Data manager
        tableView.reloadData()
        
        print("yesr")
    } catch {
        // Handle error while saving
        print("Error saving shuffled songs: \(error)")
    }
}`
```

Comment: There's no indication here of how your local `songs` array relates to your Core Data managed objects, or even how you are populating the array.  From just the code above it would appear to be an empty local property.

Comment: Also  when your array is inherently ordered, why are you storing the index as a property?  This seems like unnecessary overhead and to be asking for bugs later down the line.

Comment: I added my view did load section that is overwriting my attempting to save a new order. Do know how to add the reorder section while keeping what my code is currently doing which is displaying the names saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear how the underlying persistence layer has been implemented or the design of the `Song` class. The sort order should be inferred when fetching the data, almost certainly by specifying a `SortDescriptor`.

However as you are storing the index of each song within it's own data type you can use that when you retrieve the data:

```
songs = DataManager.shared.songs(singer: singer).sorted{$0.order < $1.order}
```

If you can make `Song` conform to `Comparable` based on its `order` property you can just use `.sorted()`